# UIWebView loading local html file cannot display the 'é' in café

Tags: iphone, html, ios, uiwebview

I am using UIWebView to load a html file in app bundle, which has some text and there is a 'é' for café, but it is displayed in simulator as: cafA©, and there is a tilde above A, how do I show that character? Is there anything like   for space?

Thanks!

Comment: I've test a café text in local html page, i have no Problem. post your htmlpage code plz?

Comment: do you have correct encoding on your page?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to bitmapdata.com and iBlue, I added this line:

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
```

and used é directly it worked.

Answer (score -1):

```
&#233; or &eacute;
```

http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/00e9/index.htm